# Run Python 2.7 by default in a Dotcloud custom service

Tags: dotcloud

I need to make Python 2.7 the default version of Python for running a Jenkins build server.  I'm trying to use `python_version` to do this, but Python 2.6 remains the default version.  I'm probably missing something really simple. Any suggestions?

*dotcloud.yml*

```
jenkins:
  type: custom
  buildscript: jenkins/builder
  ports:
    www: http
  config:
    python_version: v2.7
  processes: 
    sshagent: ssh-agent /bin/bash
    jenkins: ~/run
db:
  type: postgresql
```

*builder*

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
if [ -f ~/jenkins.war ]
then
    echo 'Found jenkins installation.'
else
    echo 'Installing jenkins.'
    wget -O ~/jenkins.war http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war/latest/jenkins.war
fi
echo 'Installing dotCloud scaffolding.'
cp -a jenkins/. ~

echo 'Setting up SSH.'
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
cp jenkins_id ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-keygen -R bitbucket.org
ssh-keyscan -H bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Can you post your build script? Normally python_version isn't available in a custom service unless you add it in your build script.

Comment: @KenCochrane Just added the build script. I'd seen your https://github.com/kencochrane/python-on-dotcloud/blob/master/python/builder project before, but hadn't thought to check the build script. But I checked it out after you mentioned the build script, and I know where you're going.  Thanks for the head's up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why my build file didn't solve the problem, but I was able to work around it by using the `--python=/usr/bin/python2.7` option for virtualenv in my Jenkins build script.

Comment: That makes sense because if you don't pass in the --python version to the VE, then it will use the default python version for the custom service which is 2.6.x . The config setting you are using in the dotcloud.yml doesn't work in the custom service out of the box, you need to add some code to your build script to take that value and change the default python version accordingly. What you are doing here, seems like a reasonable thing to do, so if it works for you, then great.